# Rotate the elements of an array to the left

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, rotation

I am trying to solve a JavaScript challenge from *jshero.net*. The challenge is this:

> Write a function rotate that rotates the elements of an array. All
> elements should be moved one position to the left. The 0th element
> should be placed at the end of the array. The rotated array should be
> returned. rotate(['a', 'b', 'c']) should return ['b', 'c', 'a'].

All I could come up with was this:

```
function rotate(a){
  let myPush = a.push();
  let myShift = a.shift(myPush);
  let myFinalS = [myPush, myShift]
  return myFinalS
}
```

But the error message I got was:

> rotate(['a', 'b', 'c']) does not return [ 'b', 'c', 'a' ], but [ 3,
> 'a' ]. Test-Error! Correct the error and re-run the tests!

I feel like I'm missing something really simple but I can't figure out what. Are there other ways to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function rotate(array){
   let firstElement = array.shift();
   array.push(firstElement);
   return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the output you are looking for, first you have to use [`Array.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to remove the first element, then using [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) add the element back to the end of the Array, then return the array, the issue is that you used the wrong oder for these steps, also `.push()` method takes element to be added as argument, here is a working snippet:

```js
function rotate(a){
  let myShift = a.shift();
  a.push(myShift);
  return a;
}

console.log(rotate(['a', 'b', 'c']));
```

Comment: It's working now. Thank you for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have created a utility where, the input array will not get mutated even after rotating the array as per the requirement.

```js
function rotate(a){
  let inputCopy = [...a]
  let myShift = inputCopy.shift();
  let myFinalS = [...inputCopy, myShift]
  return myFinalS
}

console.log(rotate([1,2,3]))
console.log(rotate(["a","b","c"]))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.unshift(...arr.splice(arr.indexOf(k)))
```

Using `unshift()`, `splice()` and `indexOf()`, this is a one line that should help. `arr` is the array you want to rotate and `k` the item you want as first element of the array. An example of function could be:

```
let rotate = function(k, arr) {
    arr.unshift(...arr.splice(arr.indexOf(k)))
}
```

And this are examples of usage:

```
let array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
let item = 'c'

rotate(item, array)
console.log(array)

// > Array ["c", "d", "a", "b"]
```

Finally back to the original array:

```
rotate('a', array)
console.log(array)

// > Array ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
function rotate(arr){
    let toBeLast = arr[0];
    arr.splice(0, 1);
    arr.push(toBeLast);
    return arr;
}
console.log(rotate(['a', 'b', 'c']));
```